# Kotlin-Volley Send JSON (post) with multiple json object in json array

Tags: json, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-volley

i am build Point Of Sales apps and i can’t able to send multiple json object in json array. My apps read from android database (SQLite) and send multiple products to server. anyone help me ? thanks

**Logcat :** E/Volley: [893] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 422 for https://…

```
override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
      headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
      headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + user_info.token
    return headers
}

override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String,String> {
    val cartRepository    = CartRespository(application)
    val transaksi = cartRepository.getByIdTrans(id_trans)

    val jo = JSONObject()
    val ja = JSONArray()

    for(i in 0 until transaksi.size){
      ja.put(i,jo.put("product_id", transaksi[i].id_item))
      ja.put(i,jo.put("jumlah", transaksi[i].kuantitas).toString())
    }

    val map = HashMap<String, String>()
      map.put("rfid", "122312")
      map.put("device", user_info.device)
      map.put("products", ja.toString())
    return map
}
```

this is my request API body, run normaly in postman.

{
    "rfid": "122312",
    "device": "1233311",
    "products": [
            {
                "product_id": 4,
                "jumlah": "1"
            }
        ]
}

Comment: I think the HTTP 422 response from the server indicates you're not making the request to the API correctly. Possibly some headers are not set.

Comment: headers already set with  (Accept,Content-Type,Authorization) @TFennis

Comment: Actually upon looking a bit closer, 422 implies that you're sending information to the server in a known format, and the content is formatted correctly but your server does not know how to interpret the data you're sending. So possibly the data you're posting to the server is invalid in some way.

Comment: Could you check the value of ja.toString(); before sending. Your JSON may be malformed.

Comment: thanks guys, the problem is solved. really appreciated